# Toggle div with same class

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm looking for a solution to toggle just the next .info div if I click "clickme". I tried many things with `next()` etc., but nothing works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
      $(".info").slideToggle();
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mbox">
  <div class="mbox-inner">
    <div class="mbox-left"><span class="mstep">1.1</span>Great</div>
    <div class="mbox-right">
      <select class="ignore" id="modul1_1">
        <option value="0">a</option>
        <option value="1">b</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clickme">Click</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing</div>

<div class="mbox">
  <div class="mbox-inner">
    <div class="mbox-left"><span class="mstep">1.2</span>Greater</div>
    <div class="mbox-right">
      <select class="ignore" id="modul1_2">
        <option value="0">a</option>
        <option value="1">b</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clickme">Click</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur s</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** to achieve that :

```
$(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.mbox').next(".info").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

The `$(this)` refer to the clicked element and `.closest('.mbox')` will get the parent with class `mbox` of clicked item, then the `.next(".info")` will select the next element with the class `info`.

**NOTE :** No need for using two ready functions.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $("<div><a class=\"close\" href=\"#\">Hinweis schliessen</a></div>").appendTo(".info");
  
  $(".clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.mbox').next(".info").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mbox">
  <div class="mbox-inner">
    <div class="mbox-left"><span class="mstep">1.1</span>Great</div>
    <div class="mbox-right">
      <select class="ignore" id="modul1_1">
        <option value="0">a</option>
        <option value="1">b</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clickme">Click</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing</div>

<div class="mbox">
  <div class="mbox-inner">
    <div class="mbox-left"><span class="mstep">1.2</span>Greater</div>
    <div class="mbox-right">
      <select class="ignore" id="modul1_2">
        <option value="0">a</option>
        <option value="1">b</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clickme">Click</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur s</div>
```

Comment: So, another one. If I also append a link to toggle the div, is it possible?

Comment: $("<div><a  class=\"close\" href=\"#\">Hinweis schliessen</a></div>").appendTo(".info");

Comment: You could add it without problem, check my update... If the answer is what you looking for mark it as **[Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.

Comment: Ok, i can add the snippet with appendTo but I'm not able to catch the link with the close class. Is I wrote the snippet directly in the code, the click function fires...

Comment: Add the code where you're trying to get the `close` class, i guess that you're not using the event delegation `on()`.

Comment: Now I wrote the links directly in the code and use prepend for the infotext.